# How to use AWK record separator?

Tags: awk

Here is the input:

```
*           true, false, yes, no, always, never.
*
*******************************************************************************
default:
    su = true
    ...
    maxexpired = -1
    umask = 077
    expires = 0

someuser:
    su = true
    ...
```

and I only need this output:

```
077
```

So I only need the "umask = 077" line for the default user. This is a snippet from /etc/security/user. "grep -p" doesn't works, because there isn't any empty line before "default:". I googled for awk record separators, but didn't found out how to do this. How can I do this? ( "..." are just other attributes.. )

UPDATE: updated the input template, Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works (code edited to get the value for only the default user):

```
awk -F'= ' '/default:/,/umask =/{ if(/umask =/){ print $2 } }' /etc/security/user
```

`-F` sets the input field separator. The code matches lines with `umask =` in them and prints their second fields.

Answer (score 1):

to pick up the `umask` value only for the `default` user

```
awk '/default:/,/umask/{if ($0 ~ /umask/){split($0, arr, "="); print(arr[2])}}' input
```